# How to use Image.ANTIALIAS with resize() in GAE?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

I am using the script below to resize images. But I noticed that the resized image looses sharpness. [According to this page](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216637) `Image.ANTIALIAS` is the best "downsizing filter". But when I add the filter to the code

```
images.resize(homepage.original_image, 200, 200, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'
```

Is there a way around this? Thanks

```
class ImageResize(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        q = HomePage.all()
        result = q.fetch(3)
        for item in result:
            firm = item.firm_name
            id = item.key().id()
            if id:
                homepage = HomePage.get_by_id(id)
                if homepage:
                    thumbnail =    images.resize(homepage.original_image, 200, 200)
                    homepage.thumbnail = db.Blob(thumbnail)
                    homepage.put()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked is for PIL but you're using the Google App Engine `images` API, the documentation for which is here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html

Comment: @ Mark Ransom: Thanks! I changed the code to: `thumbnail = images.resize(homepage.original_image, 300, 300,  images.JPEG, 100)`. For some reason the position of the `quality` argument is not indicated so I put it at the end; it is not supported in SDK so I don't know yet if this works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel The quality argument specifies the JPEG quality argument (eg, how compressed the image is); setting it higher will result in larger, sharper images, but beware about setting it too high, as it'll just waste space over a certain threshold.

Comment: @ Nick: I tried to get the size of my images by using a function similar to `size` in PIL but I could not find it in Images API. Do you know how I can get the size of an image? I am using 100 as I mentioned above and images look good.

Comment: @Zeynel, try the `width` and `height` properties. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html